# Using Google Cloud Translation API to Translate Web Content Dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm seeking guidance on how to utilize the Google Cloud Translation API within an HTML context, similar to the image provided -> [IMAGE][SELECT TRANSLATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiwkP.png). Initially, I managed to integrate the Google API directly, but I learned from an update that this method will be deprecated and only available for non-profit or non-commercial purposes. I came across this link: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/05/google-translates-website-translator?hl=pt-br

I attempted to explore the Google Cloud API documentation to obtain and activate an API key for consumption. However, the documentation doesn't provide clear instructions on how to implement a language selection (dropdown) for translating the entire webpage based on my preference.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone could assist me with this. If a backend solution is necessary, I'm using C#.

Google Cloud documentation: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/overview?hl=pt-br

I attempted various approaches outlined in the Google API documentation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think the question is detailed enough... maybe because I have the exact same question.

The 'old' Google translate could be added to a webpage using some simple JavaScript. However this 'old' version can't be used anymore (for profit) and we have to use the Google Cloud Translate API.

So the question becomes: How to use this 'new' API to add a translation dropdown to a website? Assuming that a valid licence key is available.

I would expect it to be just a small snippet of html/javascript code, but if I'm wrong then what do we need to do?

Comment: I found some example code here: <https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-google-translate-button-on-your-webpage>